# ctx filter with entire css script instead of string values?

Tags: javascript, css, canvas

Have a css script with colourful filter that hue-rotates 360 degrees and loops every 10s:

```
@keyframes rainbowEffect {
   from {filter: brightness(0.5) sepia() saturate(4) hue-rotate(0deg);}
   to {filter: brightness(0.5) sepia() saturate(4) hue-rotate(360deg);}
}
.infiniteRainbow {
   animation: rainbowEffect 10s linear infinite;
}
```

Then I have a bunch of images loaded with different categories, supposed that if the category of the image is/equals colourful, then apply the rainbow effect (filter) on them.

Got advised to use ctx.filter method. It worked with simple filters such as `'blur(4px)';`. But are there  any ways to apply the CSS scripts? (The script's filter seemed too much to fit between filter's apostrophes... )

The code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="scripts/colorful.css">
var t = deconstructImage(selected).clearName;
c = document.getElementById("frontground").getContext("2d");

if (data[t].cat === "Colourful" && !locked) {
   c.filter = 'only accepts string value, if so (how) can that css script's loop filter apply to here? '; 
   c.drawImage(document.getElementById(data["Colour man"].file))
}
```

Also, will `classList.add("infiniteRainbow")` has a chance to work as an alternative of filter method?

Comment: I'm a bit unclear why changing from CSS animation to canvas was recommended. Animating using a canvas can be very processor intensive as you'd have to redraw it specifically every frame whereas your original method using CSS means the browser can optimise use of the GPU for example. Have I misunderstood something?

Comment: It's the only way to create desired colour effect... Simply not sure how to add the animated filter onto images with .filter or classlist.add

Comment: Thanks, I may still be misunderstanding, but you can't animate a canvas as such. You have to redraw it every frame, is that what is being suggested?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by applying the filter animation to any element, then in Javascript getting a handle to that element's computed style. This will give you access to the CSS filter animation's string output, which you can then apply (in the same RequestAnimationFrame function) to the canvas's context engine before you copy the image onto the canvas.

Example on Codepen: https://codepen.io/kaliedarik/pen/XWNJaKm

HTML

```
<div id="filter-div" class="infiniteRainbow">This is a &lt;div> element. It has an animated CSS filter operating on it but shows nothing much. Current filter string: <span id="filter-string">goes here</span></div>
<p>This is an image in an &lt;img> element. It it is a flower.</p>
<img src="https://assets.codepen.io/128723/iris.png" id="iris" crossOrigin="anonymous" />

<p>This is a &lt;canvas> element. On every RAF call it will clear the canvas, apply the latest iteration of the filter string to the canvas context engine, and copy the image onto the canvas.</p>
<canvas id="my-canvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

CSS

```
@keyframes rainbowEffect {
   from {filter: brightness(0.5) sepia() saturate(4) hue-rotate(0deg);}
   to {filter: brightness(0.5) sepia() saturate(4) hue-rotate(360deg);}
}
.infiniteRainbow {
   animation: rainbowEffect 10s linear infinite;
}
```

Javascript

```
// Canvas boilerplate
const canvas = document.querySelector('#my-canvas');
const engine = canvas.getContext('2d');

// Grab handles to DOM elements
const image = document.querySelector('#iris');
const filterDiv = document.querySelector('#filter-div');
const filterDivStyles = window.getComputedStyle(filterDiv);
const filterString = document.querySelector('#filter-string');

// Animation loop that clears the canvas, resets its engine's filter attribute then draws the image onto the canvas
const animate = function () {
  
  filterString.textContent = filterDivStyles.filter;
  
  engine.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  engine.filter = filterDivStyles.filter;
  engine.drawImage(image, 0, 0, 400, 400, 0, 0, 400, 400);
  
  window.requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}

animate();
```

Comment: Thanks... Though actually realized that it was for javascript and css only, no html involved..